# Magento 2.2.1: Add Custom Upload file attribute in Checkout

Tags: checkout, attributes, magento-2.2.1

I tried to add an Upload file attribute to the Checkout form, I am now able to add a custom field, but still, I am unable to save values to the database -

I used add Plugin -

added Below code

> Amit\Fileupload\etc\di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="file_upload" type="Amit\Fileupload\Model\Plugin\Checkout\LayoutProcessor" sortOrder="100"/>        
    </type>
</config>
```

> Amit\Fileupload\Model\Plugin\Checkout\LayoutProcessor.php

```
<?php
namespace Amit\Fileupload\Model\Plugin\Checkout;
class LayoutProcessor
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array  $jsLayout
    ) {
        
            $fileupload = 'file_upload';
            $datascope = 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes';

            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
            ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children'][$fileupload] = [
                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/media',
                'config' => [
                    'customScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes',
                    'customEntry' => null,
                    'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                    'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/media',
                    'tooltip' => ['description' => 'Field to Upload File'],                 
                    'id' => $fileupload
                ],
                'dataScope' => $datascope,
                'label' => 'File Upload',
                'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                'visible' => true,
                'validation' => ['required-entry' => true],
                'options' => [],
                'sortOrder' => 250,
                'id' => $fileupload
            ];
        
        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

[image]

Now, further how to save the data of this field, looking for help on this thanks!

Comment: where (in which table) do you want to save the custom field value. Do you want to save it in any custom table?

Comment: hi Amith how did you complete this task?

Answer (score 0):

To create custom attr :

```
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $customerSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();

        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
            'custom_file',
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Custom File',
                'input' => 'file',
                'position' => 1000,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'system' => false,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'position' => 1000,
                'is_used_in_grid' => true,
                'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
                'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
                'is_searchable_in_grid' => false
            ]
        );

        $customFileAttribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'custom_file');
        $customFileAttribute->setData('used_in_forms', ['adminhtml_customer']);
        $customFileAttribute->save();

        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Define field in checkout_index_index.xml :

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="shippingAdditional" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="custom-file-upload" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Custom_Module/js/view/checkout/shipping/custom-file-upload</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Add js file in module :

```
define([
    'uiComponent'
], function (Component) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Custom_Module/checkout/shipping/custom-file-upload'
        },

        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            // add your initialization logic here
        }
    });
});
```

Create html file as per define in js file :

```
<input type="file" data-bind="
    attr: {
        'id': 'custom-file-upload',
        'name': 'custom_file'
    },
    value: customFile"
/>
```

And Add uploaded file after order in custom table with order id.

```
class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();

        $table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable(
            $installer->getTable('custom_module_uploaded_files')
        )->addColumn(
            'file_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            ['identity' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
            'File ID'
        )->addColumn(
            'order_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            ['nullable' => false],
            'Order ID'
        )->addColumn(
            'file_path',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            ['nullable' => true],
            'File Path'
        )->addIndex(
            $installer->getIdxName('custom_module_uploaded_files', ['order_id']),
            ['order_id']
        )->addForeignKey(
            $installer->getFkName('custom_module_uploaded_files', 'order_id', 'sales_order', 'entity_id'),
            'order_id',
            $installer->getTable('sales_order'),
            'entity_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::ACTION_CASCADE
        )->setComment(
            'Custom Module Uploaded Files'
        );

        $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Add below file to save data :

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface">
        <plugin name="custom_module_save_image_data" type="Custom\Module\Plugin\OrderRepositoryPlugin" sortOrder="1" disabled="false" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Add plugin class :

```
  class OrderRepositoryPlugin
    {
        public function beforeSave(OrderRepositoryInterface $subject, OrderInterface $order, $saveOptions = false)
        {
            $customImageData = $this->getCustomImageData();
            $order->setCustomImageData($customImageData);
            return [$order, $saveOptions];
        }
    
        private function getCustomImageData()
        {
            ..
        }
    }
```